# Extract arrays from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to extract some data from JSON response (from REST API to angular) into arrays to use in Chartjs.
The JSON is in this format

```
[
    {
        "A": a,
        "B": b,
        "C": c
    },
    {
        "A": aa,
        "B": bb,
        "C": cc
    },
    {
        "A": aaa,
        "B": bbb,
        "C": ccc
    }
]
```

I want it into arrays like this

```
A = [a,aa,aaa]
B = [b,bb,bbb]
C = [c,cc,ccc]
```

I just started using angular and I searched a lot for a solution. But, I couldn't find one.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any javascript/typescript before angular? Because this is a simple javascript question that has nothing specifically to do with angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved this way:

```
const obj = {};
array.forEach((item) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if(key in obj) {
            obj[key].push(value);
        } else {
            obj[key] = [value];
        }
    });
});
console.log(obj);
```